# AWS Lambda vs EC2 REST API

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, asp.net-core-webapi

I am not an expert in AWS but have some experience. Got a situation where Angular UI (host on EC2) would have to talk to RDS DB instance. All set so far in the stack except API(middle ware). We are thinking of using Lambda (as our traffic is unknown at this time). Again here we have lot of choices to make on programming side like C# or Python or Node. (we are tilting towards C# or Python based on the some research done and skills also Python good at having great cold start and C# .NET core being stable in terms of performance).
Since we are with Lambda offcourse we should go in the route of API GATEWAY. all set but now, can all the business logic of our application can reside in Lambda? if so wouldnt it Lambda becomes huge and take performance hit(more memory, more computational resources thus higher costs?)? then we thought of lets have Lambda out there to take light weight processing and heavy lifting can be moved to .NET API that host on EC2?

Not sure of we are seeing any issues in this approach? Also have to mention that, Lambda have to call RDS for CRUD operations then should I think to much about concurrency issues? as it might fall into state full category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage with AWS Lambda here is scaling. As you know already , cuz Lambda is fully managed so we can take advantages of it for this case.

If you host API on EC2, so we don't have "scaling" part in place. And of course, you can start using ECS, Auto Scaling Group ... but it is bring you to another route.

Are you building this application for learning or for production?

Comment: Hi Nghia - thanks for the response. Planning this stack for Production as dev would start soon. my concern was, is it ideal to keep all business logic(our apps have to do lot of forecasting/planning calculations after pulling the data from RDS DB) built in LAMBDA? per say there is a spike, and RDS is responding bit slow or Lambda processing logic runs slow then Lambda calls would stack up or would run in different containers concurrently due to Lambda scaling? [for each request the DB data could be different]

Comment: There is nothing wrong to keep the business logic inside Lambda. In our projects, we have around 30 lambdas running. Each of them contains a small logic. And also consider Lambda can call API(s) depends on how you want to define API layer. To complete Serverless, you can consider if you can flatten out our database to key/value, you can use DynamoDB as well. Thanks, NghiaDo

Comment: So what I take from your response is, full blown business logic can be incorporated in Lambda functions for sure. That's where I wasnt sure but thanks for your answer. Also, It seems to be the world is moving towards serverless  by choosing LAMBDA and how abt the future of MicroServices? I understand that his in the case Microservices meant lot of maintenance overhead but going microservices with ECS probably could help?

Comment: Lambda is not to replace micro-service. They can work together. I have a simple design here. Assume we are building a product which has 3 sub-systems A,B,C which is C is a platform service which can provide common services or utilities using in A,B. So A,B can be built on top of multiple AWS Lambda and those lambdas can call microservices built in C.